# Java security manager Exception

Tags: java, security, jaas

I am working on a project using the Java Authorization and Authentication Service (JAAS). I am encountering a strange security exception though:

```
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "accessClassInPackage.sun.security.util")
```

I cannot manage to understand what is the meaning of this exception. Besides, I am getting the same exception even if I grant the application all the permissions with

```
  permission java.security.AllPermission;
```

Answer (score 0):

From [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/securitymanager_checkpermission_object.htm):

> The java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Permission perm, Object
>   context) method **throws a SecurityException if the specified security
>   context is denied access to the resource specified by the given
>   permission.** The context must be a security context returned by a
>   previous call to getSecurityContext and the access control decision is
>   based upon the configured security policy for that security context.

The SecurityManager is configured by the local system and SecurityManager is responsible to protect the local system